# How do I delete a Backups.backupdb file on an external drive

Tags: backup, time-machine, permission

I have 65GB in an old Time Machine backup (`Backups.backupdb`) on a USB drive.  I'd like to delete it and reclaim the space, but none of the tricks I've seen in Apple forums are working.

- I've tried to delete it from within Time Machine, this does nothing (silently fails.)
- I've given Full Disk Access to iTerm so I can look around inside the directory, and I've run `chown -R myusername` there.
- I've disabled System Integrity Protection and rebooted, confirmed it's off using `csrutil status`, and still get "Operation not permitted" when attempting to remove files.

Anyone know what works?

Thanks -- Jon

Comment: Have you tried erasing and reformatting the drive with Disk Utility?

Comment: Yes `rm -rf` both in recovery mode and booted normally (with SIP turned off) give "Operation not permitted".

Erasing / reformatting would work, although I've another 200G on that drive I'd prefer not to stage elsewhere.

Comment: You don't specify under which user you tried to delete the file with `rm -rf ` -- can you confirm that you tried as root? Can you perhaps add the output of an `ls -@l` of your backup volume to your question, so that we can see ownership and permission info for the directory?